# Database connection through PHP & HTTPS for iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, https

Would it be sufficient to get data through a HTTPS connection into an iPhone app via PHP (the PHP files are located on the same web server as a MySQL database)?

I'm speaking in terms of security.

Also, would this be a tideous process (with too many overheads) or can it work in terms of performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question was for future reference, and I want to try out the answers before selecting a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have added HTTP authentication to the security scheme you describe--so my directory containing the PHP scripts that receive web requests from my iPhone app and emit JSON in return is behind basic web-server-level authentication. Not a LOT stronger, but it at least prevents nosy URL-twiddlers from finding their way in there.

I recommend the following third-party libraries for this:
[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)
[JSON Framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Using those two things, a `-viewDidLoad` method might contain this:

```
NSString *urlStr = @"http://username:password@myrequest.com/myjsonscript.php";
ASIHTTPRequest *r = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithUrl:
                     [NSURL urlWithString:urlStr]];
[r setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSDictionary *results = [[r responseString] JSONValue];
    //do whatever to display the background-downloaded data 
    //(possibly [self.tableView reloadData] or something like that)
}];
[r startAsynchronous];
```

Just that simple.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the best solutions i've used for accessing mysql from an iphone app (indirectly through PHP) http://tempered.mobi/

Sorry for some reason, i cant hyperlink straight to the article. But if you press Articles and then mysql json PHP, you'll see the relevant tutorial